# Rails 403 response on session expired when using protect_from_forgery

Tags: ruby-on-rails, protect-from-forgery

After a user session has expired, when making a `POST` or `PUT` request to any controller that has `protect_from_forgery`, the server responds with 403, instead of the expected 401 for logged out users.

When a controller returns a 401 code, the client will redirect the user back o the login screen.

I do not want to redirect on each 403, I don't users to get kicked out unless their session expired.

I've tried googling and played around with the different flags as described [in the doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html) without any luck. How can I make protect_from_forgery return 401 when the session expired?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a proper solution for this, so I used the following hack:

On the client side, whenever the server returns a 403 error, I immediately make a `GET` request to an API endpoint that returns 200 if the session exists (user signed in) and 401 otherwise.

I already had the client side logic of redirecting the user to the sign-in page on any 401 errors.

If anyone has a better solution that doesn't require making the seconds call I'll be happy to hear about it.